# Download File from IE11 + Create a folder to store it

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer-11, sendkeys

I had lots of issues dealing with that IE 11 download bar when downloading a file.[image]

I checked different solutions but the only way to make it work the most reliably possible was to put two of them together.

Then I set the default internet download folder as my Desktop so that whenever I download a file with SendKeys I know where to find it with the code.

For the little story, my code is downloading the attached files for all the different incident cases. The number/type of attachments can vary and to oragnize it a little bit I decided to create a folder with the name of the incident case and store the attachments inside.

Answer (score 0):

So here is my code, if you see a part which could be improved let me know :)

```
Option Explicit
Private objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Private ContentFrame As HTMLIFrame
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)


Private Sub LeftClick()
     mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
     Sleep 50
     mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub


Sub DownloadAttachment()
  'make sure Cell A4 isn't empty because it has to contain the incident case
     If Sheets(1).Cells(4, 1) = "" Or Sheets(1).Cells(4, 1) = " " Then End
  'make sure it's a valid case No. before going on
     On Error GoTo Fin
     If Len(Cells(4, 1)) <> 8 Or CLng(Sheets(1).Cells(4, 1)) = 0 Then
           MsgBox "Please enter a valid Case No."
           End
     End If
     Call GetDataFromIntranet(Sheets(1).Cells(4, 1)
  'Delete content on cell A4
     Fin:
          Sheets(1).Cells(4, 1) = ""
End Sub


Function GetDataFromIntranet(CaseNo As Long)
     Dim i As Integer
     If ("attachmentDivId").Children(0).Children(1).Children.Length >= 1 Then Call CreateFolder(CaseNo) ' If there is at least 1 attachment then we'll create a folder which has the name of the incident case
     For i = 0 To objIE.document.frames(1).frames(1).document.getElementById("attachmentDivId").Children(0).Children(1).Children.Length - 1 ' For each attachment...
RetourALaCaseDepart:
          objIE.document.frames(1).frames(1).document.getElementById("attachmentDivId").Children(0).Children(1).Children(i).Click ' Click on it so that it gets activated (blue)
          objIE.document.frames(1).frames(1).document.getElementsByName("download")(0).Click 'Click on Save as
       'The following bit send keyboard keys to cope with the Internet Downaload window that appears down the page -> downloads the file and save it on the Desktop
          Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
          Application.SendKeys "%{S}"
          Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
          SendKeys "{F6}", True
          SendKeys "{TAB}", True
          SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
       'Here we close the Desktop window which sometimes open because it can alter the SendKey codes which is very sensitive
          Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
          Dim win As Object
          For Each win In objShellWindows
               If win.LocationName = "Desktop" Then
                    win.Quit
               End If
          Next win
          Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
          If MakeSureDownloaded(objIE.document.frames(1).frames(1).document.getElementById("attachmentDivId").Children(0).Children(1).Children(i).Children(0).innerText, CaseNo) = False Then GoTo RetourALaCaseDepart ' We check if the attachment was successfully saved, if not we redo the saving process from "RetourALaCaseDepart
     Next i
     Exit Function
Fini:
     MsgBox "No attachments found or attachment tab not found"
End Function


Function MakeSureDownloaded(FileName As String, CaseNo As Long) As Boolean
     Dim FileSys As Object 'FileSystemObject
     Dim objFile As Object 'File
     Dim myFolder
     Dim strFilename As String
     Const myDir As String = "C:\Users\Seb\Desktop\"         
  'set up filesys objects
     Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'New FileSystemObject
     Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(myDir)
     For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
          If objFile.Name Like FileName & "*" Then ' If the file was saved then we will add it to the folder created earlier for that Case
               strFilename = objFile.Name
               MakeSureDownloaded = True
               GoTo BienBien
          End If
     Next objFile
     MakeSureDownloaded = False
     Set FileSys = Nothing
     Set myFolder = Nothing
     Exit Function

BienBien:
     Dim fso As Object
     Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     Call fso.MoveFile("C:\Users\Seb\Desktop\" & strFilename, "Path...\Case_Attachments\" & CaseNo & "\" & strFilename)
     Set FileSys = Nothing
     Set myFolder = Nothing
End Function


Sub CreateFolder(CaseNo As Long)
     Dim fsoFSO
     Set fsoFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     If fsoFSO.FolderExists("Path...\Case_Attachments\" & CaseNo) Then ' do nothing actually...
     Else
          fsoFSO.CreateFolder ("Path...\Case_Attachments\" & CaseNo)
     End If
End Sub
```